# How do you open the Google Voice app directly to the voicemail tab?

Tags: google, google-voice

The new Google Voice app is pretty awesome; clean, simple, usable, etc.

However, I only use GV for the voicemail functionality but the app always opens to the Messages tab.

**Is there a way to open the app directly to the Voicemail tab?**

[image: google voice voicemail picture]